How to show newer unicode characters in macOS?
For instance, ▎(Left One Quarter Block, U+258E) can be shown in macOS but not  (Right One Quarter Block, U+1FB87), not even in the Character Viewer, or on native apps like Finder & Spotlight. That character was introduced in Unicode 13 in 2020. Any ideas to show all newer unicode characters, perhaps even patching fonts to do so.

macOS can only show the characters that are in the current font that you're looking at. If the font doesn't have those glyphs, then your only option is to edit the font with a font editor, like FontForge.

Which font face have you selected in font book to do this examination? Or are you using a specific app?

If I paste it into a native app like Finder or Spotlight it just shows a box with a question mark

@Oneechan69 Being a native app is irrelevant, whether or not there is a glyph for it is what matters.  UnicodeChecker is a good tool for exploring Unicode on macOS.

Noticed this morning that the collection of fonts I have installed here on Windows 10 doesn't display U+1FB87 either, while U+258E is displayed.

The specific character you are looking for is part of the Supplementary Multilingual Plane, specifically the Symbols For Legacy Computing block.
You can gain support for many of those glyphs by installing the BabelStoneShapes font.  A link can be found at the bottom of that page.
Here it is displayed in UnicodeChecker.


I note that there is at least one other SIL-licensed font for this set of glyphs here.
